# Question got marked On Hold

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

The question itself wasn't that bad, just some code and how to access a field of an inner class. Bad title tho, ("easy easy easy").

I fixed the title, but it was already on hold. Anyway, it got 10 downvotes in no-time and put on hold after i think 5 people flagged it.

So my question is: why is a question deleted if it got a good answer that even got upvotes. Taken into account that the question wasn't really bad, maybe a bit short.

And why can you downvote without even giving a reason for it.

I hope this is better.

Comment: Life isn't fair. Better you stay off LQ questions, that are prone for deletion.

Comment: We already knew that, that's why we got sites like this.

Comment: How is this *"unfair"*, exactly?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because it was a valid question, only the topicstarter didnt put much effort in the title or the rest of the story. but asking how to acces a field of an inner class, how is that not a valid question if you don't know how to do that or got stuck on trying.

Comment: @WonderWorld if it was *"a valid question"*, I doubt it would have been put on hold then deleted, although it's hard to make a judgement without seeing it. But your question is about losing rep when questions are deleted, and you haven't answered my question; *everyone* who answers questions that are subsequently deleted lose any rep they gained, so *how is it unfair*? Why should you keep rep for content that no longer benefits the community? Upvotes on the answers are not a reflection of the quality or relevance of the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i actually don't mean the loss of reputation, i couldn't care less, i already knew that. It is more that my answer got upvotes, so some people appreciated my answer, so that is also lost due to a question that doesn't meet certain people's expectations.

Comment: @WonderWorld then please *clarify the question*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i guess the clarification is in the last sentence of my question.

Comment: @WonderWorld then get rid of the rest of it! It is evidently not clear what your argument is, so **edit the question**. If you're not asking about lost upvotes, don't put it in the title then spend most of the question talking about them.

Comment: There is also extensive discussion already on whether users should be forced to comment on downvotes (the overwhelming conclusion is no).

Answer (score 6):

A funny answer to an unbelievably crap question will always get upvotes. I've got several of them stored in my favourites for amusement later (some to find out how quick the community deleted the question later as well).

While your answer may have been good it's impossible to determine the difference between a good answer to a crap question and a bad answer to a crap question.

I have no idea whether the question you answered should have been deleted because I don't have the tools to find it. But, if it should have been deleted then why should you keep reputation from answers that don't help the site? Just because your answer got 3 upvotes doesn't mean that the question isn't off-topic.

**Moral of the story; don't answer questions that are off-topic.**

Comment: First of all it wasn't a funny answer. :) But secondly, how can a question be concidered off topic if other people bothered to upvote my answer. Well i guess a lot were bugged by the question since it got 10 downvotes. Better for the guy that it got deleted.

Comment: @WonderWorld Because people are *people*, not machines. Some of them will upvote. Some others of them will consider the question off-topic and downvote, or vote to close. It's not as though there's a Borg collective deciding how to handle each question.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Personally i never downvote, i don't like it.

Comment: @Ben so if i deleted this question now... i mean i got 6 downvotes, 7 now.. you got 6 upvotes...

Comment: @WonderWorld You don't lose or gain rep on meta

Comment: @Rizier123 i hope it bugs the downvoters lol

Comment: @WonderWorld nope, am not bugged by it at all